# TestNG framework, @Test Annotation code is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

TestNG framework, @Test Annotations is not working for me, everything else is perfect, i have also tried by copy pasting the tutorials code and applied the same code but not fruitful...

Comment: How about adding the relevant code?

Comment: What was the point of this question? This post makes no sense what-so-ever.  Please research your issues first.  Then at least TRY to solve it on your own - come here prepared to show us what you've tried first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please ensure below things:
1. Importing testng
`import org.testng.annotations.Test;`

2.If maven, add below dependency to POM.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.9.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

3.Import Testng.jar in case of non-maven project.

If still issue persists, kindly post error message.